# Conversion is ambiguous in Visual Studio 2015, but not with clang

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, clang

The following code, a simplified version of code found in the googlemock project, fails to compile in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, but it compiles on clang [Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)].

```
struct ConvertibleFromAny
{
    ConvertibleFromAny(int a_value);

    template <typename T>
    ConvertibleFromAny(const T& a_value);
};

template <typename T>
struct Matcher
{
    Matcher(T value);
};

template <typename Rhs>
struct EqMatcher
{
    explicit EqMatcher(const Rhs& rhs);

    template <typename Lhs>
    operator Matcher<Lhs>() const;
};

int main()
{
    EqMatcher<ConvertibleFromAny> em(1);
    Matcher<ConvertibleFromAny> m = em;

    return 0;
}
```

The error occurs at the <del>assignment</del> statement

```
Matcher<ConvertibleFromAny> m = em;
```

and the error message is

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'EqMatcher<ConvertibleFromAny>' to 'Matcher<ConvertibleFromAny>'
note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

I can naively see an ambiguity between a member call to

```
EqMatcher<ConvertibleFromAny>::operator Matcher<ConvertibleFromAny>()
```

and an initialization conceptually similar to

```
Matcher<ConvertibleFromAny> m(ConvertibleFromAny<EqMatcher<ConvertibleFromAny>>(em))
```

My guess is that clang rules out the second option.

EDIT: Inspired by T.C.'s comment I tested the following:

```
struct A
{
};

struct X
{
    X(const A&);
};

struct B
{
    B(const X&);
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    B b = a;
}
```

It compiles with VS 2015, but not with clang. I have not been able to find any references that documents that the Visual C++ implementation intentionally deviates from the standard in this regard.

Is this a well-known problem?

Comment: The second option is not viable - it runs afoul of the "one user-defined conversion" rule. Clang is right.

Comment: `Matcher<ConvertibleFromAny> m = em;` is not an assignment.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the code compiles fine with VS2013. I suppose it's a bug in VS 2015 but could not find any issue report on it.

Comment: Have you tried `B b{a}` ?

Comment: @mvd I see similar results on VS2013 and VS2015. The first example does not compile, the second example does.

Comment: @mvd Went back and retried the examples on VS2013 and it turns out that the original example _does_ compile on VS2013. It prefers the conversion function over the non-standard conversion. The second example produces similar result on either compiler.

Answer (score 12):

Both your code samples produce the expected result with VS2015 Update 1, if I enable the "Disable Language Extensions" (`/Za`) flag. That is, the first one compiles, the second one does not.

I'm not sure *which* extension in particular is interfering here, though.
I found this MSDN page: [Microsoft Extensions to C and C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx), but it does not appear to be complete - for example, binding a non-const T& to an rvalue is not mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

> I have not been able to find any references that documents that the
>   Visual C++ implementation intentionally deviates from the standard in
>   this regard.

Here you go: [Compiler Warning (level 1) C4928](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwck4ta9.aspx). The message is

> illegal copy-initialization; more than one user-defined conversion has been implicitly applied

It *also* says this:

> The compiler executed the code in all such routines.

So there's a *de facto* language extension that Microsoft has only barely documented.

You can use command line argument `/we4928` to convert the warning into an error, effectively removing this single extension. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx) for these arguments.

Comment: This seems highly relevant, but strangely, I can't get the compiler to produce the warning for any of the examples above. The example from the linked documentation works as advertised.

Comment: I think if this worked for all cases it would be preferrable. Disabling all extensions makes some MS headers unusable IIRC.